# Doubt on the equality of the two integrals.

Tags: integration

We define $D_N(x)= \sum_{-N}^{N} e^{inx}$ (the dirichlet kernel).

I have to show $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)D_N(x-t) dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x-t)D_N(t) dt$

Let $G(y)=f(y)D_N(x-y)$

I have shown that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}G(x-t) dx= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} G(t) dt$

My proof -

Set $\phi(y)=x-y$. Thus we have that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} G(\phi(t))\phi '(t)=\int_{-\phi(\pi)}^{\phi(\pi)} G(t) dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} G(t) dt$ since $G$ is periodic with period $2\pi$. Now $\phi '(t) dt=dx $ which implies our result.

Can someone help me to use something similar to solve the original problem? Thanks.

Edit : It is mentioned that $f$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ and $D_N(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$ because of the formula $D_N(x)=\frac{\sin ((N+\frac{1}{2})x)}{\sin (\frac{t}{2})}$

Answer (score 1):

The equation is valid under  the assumption that $f$ is also periodic with period $2\pi$. It is fasle without this assumption.

Use the same arguement:  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)D_N(x-t) dt = \int_{x-\pi}^{x+\pi} f(x-y)D_N(y) dt =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x-y)D_N(y) dt$ by perodicity.